Force setuptools to skip cache for certain python dependencies
Is there an option in the setup.cfg install_requires or in alternately in the pyproject.toml file to skip the cache when loading certain pip dependencies.
I have libraries in a local PyPi repository that get updated during development and I don't want to have to go through the hassle of having to update the version every time I want to make change. I also don't want to disable the cache entirely so that third-party libraries have to be reloaded for every build.

Nope, no way. All cache or no cache.
